# Why does WPF grid use attached properties for row and column?

Tags: .net, wpf

In WPF, if I want to use a Grid layout, I need to set row and column definitions...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Cell data goes here -->
</Grid>
```

...and then define the position of items in the grid using the attached `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties:

```
<TextBlock Text="Name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

<TextBlock Text="Age:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Age}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

This creates at least two problems I can think of:

1. If I have a bunch of rows and want to insert something after the first row, then I need to reassign `Grid.Row` for all items from the second row onwards.
2. If I decide to hide a row (e.g. based on whether a user has a particular permission), the row will still take up the same space.

This use of attached properties to explicitly annotate the position of every element in the grid contrasts with the HTML approach, where rows and cells are defined sequentially:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td>John</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Age:</td><td>15</td></tr>
</table>
```

In HTML, the scenarios mentioned above are very easily addressed. You can insert a new row just by... inserting it:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Title:</td><td>Mr.</td></tr> <!-- insert win -->
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td>John</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Age:</td><td>15</td></tr>
</table>
```

...and remove a row just by... removing it:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Title:</td><td>Mr.</td></tr> <!-- insert win -->
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td>John</td></tr>
    <!-- no more age! and it doesn't take up space any more either -->
</table>
```

I know very well that WPF is very different from HTML. Why did the WPF designers go with this approach? And are there any ways to address the above-mentioned problems?

Comment: How else would you set the row and column values if it didn't use Attached Properties? Your examples are invalid because XAML is far from HTML. You have just added a single `string` into your cells, but in reality in XAML, you could add several hundred lines into each cell and so you'd soon lose the `Grid` definition amongst all of the cell contents.

Comment: The same way HTML does it - using row and cell containers.

Comment: Isn\`t HTML table mainly data presentation control and not layout control? Then the more appropriate comparison will be DataGrid, not Grid.

Comment: I used to make desktop apps with WPF.  Now I make web applications almost exclusively.  It pains me to see a complaint about how the Grid doesn't work like an HTML table.  IMO, the layout options available in HTML are pathetic compared with WPF.  What I wouldn't give to have a Grid in HTML!

Comment: *The same way HTML does it*... I just explained why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed something which could be very annoying.

In scenarios I need to stack items one below the other, I just use a StackPanel.
But in case you really want the grid functionality, there's a very neat solution:

[AutoGrid](https://github.com/carbonrobot/wpf-autogrid)

Using the AutoGrid allows you to define the number of rows and columns, and every element you add to the grid is automatically assigned a row and column values:

```
<AutoGrid RowCount="2" RowHeight="35" Columns="100,auto">
  <Label />
  <TextBox />
  <Label />
  <TextBox />
</AutoGrid>
```

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which unlike AutoGrid is actually included in the framework.

Answer (score 3):

It's just another example of a tradeoff of power for more specification. You have more control over the grid in WPF, at the cost of having to specify more attributes. You don't need to specify as much in the HTML because it makes assumptions about how you will be using that tag  - which can be good or bad. What if I don't want all my rows to have the same height by default? How much harder would it be to declare in HTML the "star notation?"

However, I don't think it's as different as you might think. In order to dynamically hide that HTML 
row, you would have to set the `display` to `none`, and in WPF, you would have to set the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` and change the `RowDefinition`'s `Height`.

The reason the designers went with this approach is that it does allow for more flexibility - `Grid` is primarily a layout manager, not a table display. The attached properties method gives (again, at the cost of having to specify more attributes) a lot more control, which is important for layout managers (although yes they can be a pain in the butt sometimes if you've ever done GUI).

Also, for the purposes of dynamically adding rows to a grid for showing data, you probably wouldn't use a `Grid`, but `DataGrid`. You can also use `UniformGrid`, which is similar to HTML's table (though this is still a layout manager). There is also a `Table` class.